# mySQL subquery returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a table for blog posts. if a user reblogs a post, then the `source_hash` field is filled with the original post's hash. I could store the original post's author (username) as well, but if they change their username... well, you see where I'm going.

So what I'm trying to do is get all of the post's information, PLUS the original author's username from a subquery using the `source_hash` field from the parent query. Everything works perfectly except for the subquery - it's returning NULL.

I've stripped out some of the query (it's rather large) to get to the meat of it. Hopefully this makes sense!

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS pid 
, p.uid
, p.hash
, p.source_hash
  ...
, u.id AS uid
, u.username
, u.avatar 

, s.username AS source

FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.uid=u.id 
...

# problematic subquery
LEFT JOIN users s ON (SELECT username FROM posts po LEFT JOIN users s ON s.id=po.uid WHERE po.hash=p.source_hash)

WHERE p.uid=1 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Edit: I've created a SQL Fiddle and whittled down everything to it's most basic components. In the fiddle, the `source` column should return `lindsey`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0183e/2

Comment: Is your all independent subquery has the data, did you test that

Comment: @anish Yes, subquery gets the correct username when i provide the hash `SELECT s.username FROM posts po LEFT JOIN users s ON s.id=po.uid WHERE po.hash='2djeij83k'`

Comment: Is it possible to post the table structures and some test data?. A [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be helpful.

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks for looking, I've created a fiddle with the most basic components: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0183e/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ON condition where you use subquery is problematic in your query - in short it's wrong.

I would write next query in this case (tested, returns correct results):

```
SELECT 
  p.id AS pid 
, p.uid
, p.hash
, p.source_hash
  ...
, u.id AS uid
, u.username
, u.avatar 

, u2.username AS source

FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.uid=u.id 
...

# instead of subquery use left join with posts again for source post
LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p.source_hash = p2.hash
# then join source post with another user table to get source username
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = p2.uid

WHERE p.uid=1 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC
```